# Facebook ids_for_pages returns "An owning business is required"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to connect 2 scoped ids of the same user from Messenger and private_replies API call.

When I call ids_for_pages with the private_replies senderId I get this response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) An owning business is required for this request",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "C1wGrChj+O3"
   }
}
```

Any idea what this means?

Comment: The app and the page must be associated with the same business first ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is a bit old, but I faced the same problem today because the error is not clear at all. To solve this, you need to be sure that your page and app are linked or "owned" by the same business, to do that you must go to the business manager:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/business-manager#update-business