# How can I get messenger user ID from facebook user ID

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, react-native, deep-linking

i am using react native to build my app. I have facebook user id. I have a button which will be used to be clicked to show the specific user in messenger. The facebook id and messenger id is different for the user. I want to open the user tab on messenger app using **Linking.openURL('https://m.me/{user-id}')** . where i need to put {user-id}. So how can i retrieve messenger id from facebook id? I got the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching which is confusing for me. I tried

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{user-id}?fields=name,age_range,ids_for_apps,ids_for_pages&access_token=[access-token]&appsecret_proof=[appsecret-proof]
```

it shows:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) An owning business is required for this request",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "HTWx/j5Oq/S"
   }
}
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: what´s confusing about the link? your use case is in the examples: "Given a user ID for an app, retrieve the IDs for bots in Messenger owned by the same business"

Comment: @luschn i updated what confuses me. please tell me how to solve.

Comment: are you using a page token?

Comment: i found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514010/facebook-ids-for-pages-returns-an-owning-business-is-required

Comment: I have seen this link. Found no clue there. I am using access_token what facebook gives when login. @luschn